# Wagtail Form not validating when submitted empty

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, templatetags, wagtail

I have created a "Subscribe" form using Wagtail form builder, with one email field that is required, I have also created a template tag to use this form in different places on the web site.

**The problem:**

If the user submits the form with an incomplete email address, I'll get a validation error (which is expected).  However, if the user submits the form without providing an email address, wagtail sends the user to the actual form url and prompts the user to fill out the form again.

The behavior should be, that if the form is submitted without an email address, a validation error should be triggered as well, this is not happening.

**Here is the form model code:**

```
class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    page = ParentalKey('SubscribeForm', related_name='form_fields')

class SubscribeForm(AbstractEmailForm):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Form fields"),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text', classname="full"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('to_address', classname="full"),
            FieldPanel('from_address', classname="full"),
            FieldPanel('subject', classname="full"),
        ], "Email")
    ]
```

**Here is the custom template tag code:**

```
from django import template
from home.models import *

register = template.Library()

# Subscribe

@register.inclusion_tag('home/subscribe_form.html', takes_context=True)
def vdecristo_subscribe(context):

    page = SubscribeForm.objects.get(slug='subscribase')
    return {
        'request': context['request'],
        'page': page,
        'form': page.get_form(),
    }
```

**Here is the html code:**

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags  vdecristo_tags %}

<!-- Callout Subscribe Form Green -->


        <div class="shop-subscribe bg-color-green margin-bottom-40">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 md-margin-bottom-20">
                                <h2>Subscribase para mantenerse<strong> informado</strong></h2>
                        </div>

                    <form action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group">

                            <input id="id_subscribase" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electronico..." name="subscribase"
                                 type="email">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></button>
                            </span>


                     </form>


                                </div>


                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div><!--/end container-->
        </div>
```

Can somebody shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know without seeing your `views.py` code, but reloading the empty form is the kind of thing that happens when the `if request.method == 'POST' ...` portion of the view isn't receiving the `request.POST` form data.